# Algoritmo de fatoração em C

Tags: c, while, fatorial

Ao criar um algoritmo de fatoriais de números com **while** vejo que, ao fazer input do número 21 em diante, o resultado sai errado -negativo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int i=1, ii=1, num, fat=1, somatorio;

int main (){

  while(i <=  5){
    printf("Insira um número: ");
    scanf("%ld", &num);

    ii = 1;
    fat = 1;
    
    while(ii <= num){
      fat = fat * ii;
      ii++;
    }

    printf("Fatorial: %ld\n",fat);

    somatorio = fat + somatorio; 

    i++;

  }
    printf("\nSomatório dos fatoriais: %ld\n\n", somatorio);
}
```

O programa deve ler 5 números e ao final apresentar o somatório das fatoriais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Intervalo do dado

O valor negativo que está retornando do fatorial é por conta que as variáveis estão sendo declarado como tipo `long int` que tem um intervalo de (-2.147.483.648 a 2.147.483.647), nesse caso para contorna o erro utiliza o tipo de dado `unsigned long long int` que tem o maior intervalo

### Tipos de dados e modificadores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Código

Segue o código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int i=1, ii=1, num, fat=1, somatorio;

int main (){

while(i <=  5){
    printf("Insira um número: ");
    scanf("%ld", &num);

    ii = 1;
    fat = 1;

    while(ii <= num){
      fat = fat * ii;
      ii++;
    }

    printf("Fatorial: %llu\n",fat);

    somatorio = fat + somatorio;

    i++;

}
    printf("\nSomatório dos fatoriais: %llu\n\n", somatorio);
}
```

O número limite fatorial é 20! após esse número excede o 64 bits proposto pelo tipo de dado `unsigned long long int`.